# What does it mean by with parameter 6 and 8?

Tags: c++

I am working on an assigment and i am stuck on this question.
Its in a book and i cant understand what the program wants?

[image: Question]

I take a value from user and stores it in z.i dont have the value of 'a'.Suppose i also get that from user.i create a variable 'first' and assign it with function one done but what does it mean by with parameters 6 and 8?

This was already in book. i have done a part of question but b i cant understand.

```
 int one(int x, int y);
    double two(int x, double a);
    int main()
    {
    int num;
    double dec;
    .
    .
    .
    return 0;
    }
int one(int x, int y)
{
.
.
.
}
double two(int x, double a)
{
int first;
double z;
.
.
.
}
```

I will be thankful for your help

Comment: It means that you should pass 6 and 8 to `one`.

Comment: 6 and 8 what???

Comment: Do `first = one(6,8)`.

Comment: @DoctorStrange Not six and eight of anything – the numbers six and eight.

Comment: Please Refrain from posting text as an image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in the 6 and 8 in the function one and give the value of the function one.
Like:

```
double two(int x, double a){
    int first = one(6,8);   
 }
```

if you would do it step by step:

```
double two(int x, double a){
   /*step 1*/
    int z = 0;
    std::cin >> z;

   /*step 2*/
    z=z+a;
   /*step 3*/
   int first = one(6,8);   

   /*step 4*/
   first = first + x;
 }
```

I will let you work it out the last one!
Good Luck!